# 4×6 Rectangle With A Twist

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

It is known that a $4\times6$ grid can be colored with two colors such that no four cells of the same color form an axis-aligned rectangle. The only valid coloring, up to permutation of its columns, is

> [image: valid coloring of 4 by 6]

**The question is: is there a $4\times6$ grid, colored with two colors, such that no four cells of the same color form any rectangle, axis-aligned or otherwise?**

Clearly, rectangles must be non-degenerate.

Comment: What do you mean by "the diagonal"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the following works

> This arrangement is symmetric - mirroring top-to-bottom is equivalent to swapping the colours. Therefore you need only check a single colour for the existence of a rectangle.
>
> ```
> O X O X
> O X X O
> O O X X
> X X O O
> X O O X
> X O X O
> ```